# How can I style my application with no borders?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, xaml

I've seen it here and there, recently on my Visual Studio updater:

[image]

Is that a predefined style to get that nice and sleek ui? I want the window with no border but still the close and minimize button.

Is that a window style of some sort?

Comment: If you are using WPF, then you could use either MahApps.Metro (http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/) OR Modern UI (http://mui.codeplex.com/) to achieve something similar to that screen. But I am not too sure whether it is possible for it to be used within a WinForm app.

Comment: @gregory.bmclub I was just about to write that :) I've used MahApps.Metro before and can vouch for it.

Comment: @gregory.bmclub You can do anything in a Windows Forms app, pretty much. You can hit the Windows API if necessary.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I've not touched any WinForms stuff so I wasn't too sure about that! My expertise (if you can call it that, lol) is through WPF. But that is very interesting what you have just mentioned. :)

Comment: MahApps.Metro rocks! Thanks (answer and ill accept)

Comment: @Jason94 Hope it helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

In Winforms you could just set `FormBoarderStyle` to none so the Borders disappear.

In WPF you could set the `WindowStyle="None"`.

In both cases you could just implement your buttons yourself:

```cs
this.Close(); //Close
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized; //Minimize
```